# technical details on how to provision an interconnect between the adsense network and our servers for dynamic video ad stitching

Tags: video-streaming, adsense, wowza

please suggest a better SO sister site if this question i snot a good fit for SO.

I have a technical implementation question.  We have a video service that provides a video platform and player to the end viewer. Currently any video ad is requested and stitched client side. We are looking into the is possibility for us to do server side stitching of the ad and embed it into the stream, not client side. We use wowza and cloudfront for distribution.

Where would I find very technical details on how to provision such an interconnect between the adsense network and our servers?

Thanks Art.

Comment: Do you need ad overlays or inserted clips? If overlays are fine, you can use [Clamp](https://streamtoolbox.com/clamp)

Comment: @jabal, we are after insert not overlay, but thank you for the link anyway.